# Контроль памяти

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть ли какой-нибудь инструмент, который бы мониторил работу с памятью в с++ проекте? Интересует следующий функционал:

- Контроль утечек.
- Контроль границ.
- Контроль доступа по освобожденным указателям.

Фактически нужен функционал делфийской библиотеки [FastMM](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4) в режиме FullDebugMode

Все это под MSVC

Comment: @DSuhoi а при чем сдесь умные указатели? Сдесь явно функционал `valgrind` и `leak sanitizer`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я так понял, что это все под Linux?

Comment: нет, не только под Linux, но valgrind не доступен под windows, а вот AdressSanitizer зависит лишь от компилятора и может быть собран g++ или clang

Comment: Там целая куча этих инструментов, visual leak detector, встроенный профилировщик память, всякие санитайзеры, Application Verifier.

Comment: я лично пробовал все эти виндовые "поделки" -  они либо не работают (ничего не находят), либо их просто не удалось завести. А вот под линуксом с пол пинка  все инструменты работают. Сам хотел бы увидеть хотя бы один нормальный инструмент под винду (есть коллега, который уже год ищет странный креш, скорее всего связанный с удаленным указателем в QT приложении).